# How to create an .exe file that shuts down a remote computer in VB.NET?

Tags: windows, vb.net

I'm trying to create an .exe file that shuts down a remote computer using VB.NET.

I can achieve this using the `shutdown` command from a `.bat` file but my goal is to achieve this using an `.exe` file which takes a computer name and reboots it.

Is this possible?

If so, how should I do it?

Comment: You think of something like [this](https://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html)?

Comment: It is possible and the easiest route would be to shell out and run the shutdown.exe app from vb.net.

Comment: You should indeed execute shutdown.exe, which you would do by calling `Process.Start`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have a program asking for a IP in a textbox.

So, the easiest way to do this is to run this code after the user finishes typing the IP:

```
Process.Start("shutdown.exe -s -t 0 -m " & TextBox1.Text)
```

Now, this is the most simplistic way of doing so and I haven't tried out this code, so I can't guarantee you that it works. I'd also recommend you to add validation to check if the user input is a IP.

I hope this helped you. -Luca